# c++ file reading into memory

Tags: c++, function

i'm trying to load the file into an array when the program starts so i can 
modify or search in it i don't know if my code works or not ( it's not reading the file )i have the file 
and there's two books in

i have tried to debug it but couldn't find the problem the code works
but it think there's a problem with the load() function i don't know what

my code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

struct books{
//identfying books with all needed things
int id, status;
string title, p_name, p_address;
string date;
string aut_name, aut_nationality;
}newbook[10000], aut[10000];
int i = 0;

void load(){
ifstream myfile("books.txt", ios::in);
while (myfile >> newbook[i].id >> newbook[i].title >> newbook[i].p_name >> newbook[i].p_address >> aut[i].aut_name >> aut[i].aut_nationality >> newbook[i].date >> newbook[i].status)
    i++;
}
void search_for_book(){
int temp = 0;
int idx;
cout << "enter the ID of the book you're looking for : ";
cin >> idx;

for (int srh = 0; srh < i; srh++){
    if (newbook[srh].id == idx){
        cout << setw(10) << "book found :" << endl;

        cout << "title :" << newbook[srh].title << endl;
        cout << "publisher name : " << newbook[srh].p_name << endl;
        cout << "publisher address" << newbook[srh].p_address << endl;
        cout << "author name :" << aut[srh].aut_name << endl;
        cout << "author Nationality :" << aut[srh].aut_nationality << endl;
        cout << "publish Date :" << newbook[srh].date << endl;
        cout << "status :" << newbook[srh].status << endl;
        temp++;
        break;
    }

    else
        srh++;
}
if (temp == 0){
    cout << "couldn't find book" << endl << endl;
}

}
int main(){
load();
char choice;
cout << "enter your choice (3)";
cin >> choice;
if (choice == '3'){
    search_for_book();
}

}
```

note :*( there are other functions like adding new book but not necessary to write )

*(i'm new to c++ don't really know how to read file into memory but i'm trying)

this is the code to save data into file :

```
void add_new_book_5(){

int booksnumber;
books newbook[1000], aut[100];
cout << "how many books you want to add ? ";
cin >> booksnumber;
cout << "what books you want to add :" << endl;
d_base.open(path, ios::out | ios::app);
for (int i = 0; i < booksnumber; i++){
    cout << "id please : "; cin >> newbook[i].id;
    cout << "title : ";              cin.ignore();   getline(cin, newbook[i].title);
    cout << "publisher name :";                      getline(cin, newbook[i].p_name);
    cout << "publisher address : ";                  getline(cin, newbook[i].p_address);
    cout << "author" << " name : "; cin.ignore();    getline(cin, newbook[i].aut_name);
    cout << "Nationality : ";                                    getline(cin, newbook[i].aut_nationality);
    cout << "Publish date :";                                        getline(cin, newbook[i].date);
    cout << "How many copies of " << newbook[i].title << " ";       cin >> newbook[i].status;

    system("cls");

    d_base << newbook[i].id << "\ " << newbook[i].title << "\ ";
    d_base << newbook[i].p_name << "\ " << newbook[i].p_address << "\ ";
    d_base << newbook[i].aut_name << "\ " << newbook[i].aut_nationality << "\ ";
    d_base << newbook[i].date << "\ " << newbook[i].status << endl;

}

d_base.close();

cout << setw(76) << "Books Have Been Saved Sucessfully" << endl;

}
```

Comment: "*i don't know if my code works or not*", it is not clear what your question is. Is something not working for you?

Comment: i guess it's not reading the file

Comment: Now is a good opportunity for you to learn how to use a debugger, and step through your code, line by line, and see whether or not your suspicions are true. Once you did that, if you still don't understand why your code took some particular steps, you can update this question, explain what you saw your code doing.

Comment: I notice that you have `int i` as a global variable which is being used by both `load()` and `search_for_book()` - avoid doing this, it will inevitably cause problems somewhere in your code at some point.

Comment: i want to use it in them both becouse im searching in the array which should have been loaded from the file in the load() function @ArchbishopOfBanterbury

Comment: @SamVarshavchik i did but  couldn't fix it

Comment: Exactly what did you? Did you see your code step through the while loop, once per each line of the file? What was the value of `i`, after the while loop, that loaded the file, finished?

Comment: i tried to put a cout in the function for the array of of i and it didn't work too and also i tried to see the value of i after the load and it was 0

Comment: it could be because your long chained read operations failed some where along the line and terminating the loop.

Comment: i can't figure it out is my syntax right ? @bkVnet

Comment: if the read operation in the `while` loop fails, then the loop will terminate and `i` would be 0 at the end. so make sure the file exists,check if it is opened successfully before reading(`if(myfile.fail()) //file not opened...`),possibly break those chained read operations to separate lines and try to use a debugger to see where the operation fails(if it does).

Comment: instream >> stringVar reads a single word, whereas outstream << stringVar writes the entire string. That may be the reason why load fails (possibly while reading int status)

Comment: Could you show the code that saves data into a file?

Comment: @alexm this is the code to save data into file^